# Bash For Loop With If & Elif Logic Broken

Tags: bash

I've been playing with bash scripting for 40'ish days with 0 experience so forgive me if my code looks like crap.  I have a script that will take the configured NTP servers out of the /etc/ntp.conf file (/root/ntp.conf for testing)

```
NTPSRVCounter=1
echo "--- NTP Configuration ---"
echo " "
while read -r line; do
    if [ $NTPSRVCounter == 1 ] ; then
        echo "Primary NTP: $line"
        SEDConfiguredNTP1="$(echo $line | sed 's/\./\\./g')"
        ((NTPSRVCounter++))
        echo " "
            else
        SEDConfiguredNTP2="$(echo $line | sed 's/\./\\./g')"
        echo "Secondary NTP: $line"
        echo ""  
    fi
    done < <(grep -o -P '(?<=server ).*(?= iburst)' /root/ntp.conf)
```

And asks you if you want to change it with a case statement:

```
echo "Do you wish to change it? [Y/n]"
NTPSRVCounter2=1
read opt
case $opt in
    Y|y) read -p "Enter in your primary NTP server: " -e -i '0.debian.pool.ntp.org' UserInputNTP1
    read -p "Enter in your secondary NTP serer: " -e -i '1.debian.pool.ntp.org' UserInputNTP2
    for NTP in "$UserInputNTP1" "$UserInputNTP2" ; do
        is_fqdn "$NTP"
            if [[ $? == 0 && $NTPSRVCounter2 == 1 ]] ; then
                SEDUserInput1=$(echo $UserInputNTP1 | sed 's/\./\\./g')
                ((NTPSRVCounter2++))
            elif [[ $? == 0 && $NTPSRVCounter2 == 2 ]] ; then 
                SEDUserInput2=$(echo $UserInputNTP2 | sed 's/\./\\./g')
                sudo sed -i "s/$SEDConfiguredNTP1/$SEDUserInput1/g" /root/ntp.conf
                sudo sed -i "s/$SEDConfiguredNTP2/$SEDUserInput2/g" /root/ntp.conf
            else
                echo "Fail!!! :-( "
            fi
        done

     ;;

     N|n) return 0

     ;;

     *) echo "I don't know what happened, but, eh, you're not supposed to be here."
     ;;
     esac
```

The problem is with the "elif" statement and the function "is_fqdn" on the second run of the function.  If I put "bash -x" on the script and run it, I see "is_fqdn" returning 0 on both runs of the function, but the elif statement "$?" is coming up as 1 instead of 0.

The two functions used are below.  Have to validate NTP addresses as either valid domain names or I.P. addresses, right?  :)

```
is_fqdn() {
hostname=$1
if [[ "$hostname" =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
    valid_ip "$hostname"
elif [[ "$hostname" == *"."* && "$hostname" != "localhost." && "$hostname" != "localhost" ]] ; then
    return 0
else
    return 1
fi
host $hostname > /dev/null 2>&1 || return 1
}


valid_ip(){
local stat=1
local ip=$1
if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
    OIFS=$IFS
    IFS="."
    ip=($ip)
    IFS=$OIFS
    [[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255 && ${ip[2]} -le 255 && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]]
    stat=$?
fi
return "$stat"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in your `if` sets the value of `$?`, and that is what's used by the condition in the `elif` part, not the return value of `is_fqdn`. You need to save the value if you want to use it in multiple places:

```
is_fqdn "$NTP"
is_fqdn_rv=$?
if [[ $is_fqdn_rv == 0 && $NTPSRVCounter2 == 1 ]] ; then
  SEDUserInput1=$(echo $UserInputNTP1 | sed 's/\./\\./g')
  ((NTPSRVCounter2++))
elif [[ $is_fqdn_rv == 0 && $NTPSRVCounter2 == 2 ]] ; then 
  SEDUserInput2=$(echo $UserInputNTP2 | sed 's/\./\\./g')
  sudo sed -i "s/$SEDConfiguredNTP1/$SEDUserInput1/g" /root/ntp.conf
  sudo sed -i "s/$SEDConfiguredNTP2/$SEDUserInput2/g" /root/ntp.conf
else
  echo "Fail!!! :-( "
fi
```